# Random class for c++

Tags: c++, random

I want for a project in C++, to have a class that has the functionality that Random class has in java or in c#

I have found this one, http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet342.htm but it has bugs and I can't quite fix them right now.

Could you point out the bugs and their fixes, or suggest another implementation?

Comment: Do you have [c++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Extensible_random_number_facility) available?

Comment: If you have found bugs, it would be easier for people to fix them if you actually told them which they were. And better place to write about the bugs would probably be in the comments for the post you linked.

Comment: In the absence of C++0x, have you looked at [Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_random.html)?

Comment: The first one it the one in the original's site comments. The first call to uniform always give the same number. The second one is that from uniform(8) I might get as a result a big number as 4253351777

Comment: @George: Maybe you forgot to use it properly. PRNGs usually need seeding.

Comment: No the seeding is ok (time(NULL))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: http://bedaux.net/mtrand/

Comment: Thx! That probably will do it. I'll test it :)

Answer (score 8):

There are three nearly identical, high-quality "standard" random number generation libraries that you should try to find in descending order:

- C++11's `<random>`.
- The TR1's `<tr1/random>`
- Boost's `<boost/random.hpp>`.

They're all conceptually identical and even practically near-identical, apart from the namespace (`std`, `std::tr1` and `boost`, respectively).

Each library defines a set of *engines*, such as `std::mt19937`. Pick one (for each thread) and seed it.

Once you have an engine, you can use a wide variety of *distributions* to generate numbers, using your engine. Frequently used distributions are uniform integers in a range [a, b], uniform floats in the range [0,1), and several well-known probability distributions like the normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I actually have one implemented: http://frigocoder.dyndns.org/svn/Frigo/Math, see Random, Random.cpp and MersenneTwister

Random is an abstract class though unlike in Java, I had no desire to implement silly LCG generators by default. It has no nextGaussian method either. MersenneTwister inherits from it.

They have a lot of dependencies on my library, but they can be easily removed, and you have the general idea.